# Possible to removeLaravel Middleware based on session

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I am trying to remove a `middleware` based on a `session key`, is it possible?

So far I tried this

```php
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {  
        if(Session::has('imperson_by')) {
            $this->withoutMiddleware(['2fa.enabled', '2fa.confirm']);
        }
    });
}
```

My Route

```
Route::group([
    'namespace' => 'Employee',
    'prefix' => 'employee',
    'middleware' => [
        'auth',
        '2fa.enabled',
        '2fa.confirm',
    ],
], function () {
    Route::get('/', [EmployeeController::class, 'index'])->name('employer.index');
    Route::get('/data', [EmployeeController::class, 'data'])->name('employee.data');
});
```

Comment: If those are your middleware it's easier to modify their code to add that exception. If they are not you should be able to extend them in your own code and check the condition before running `parent::handle...`

Comment: As I know you can't remove dynamically

Answer (score 0):

please handle the conditions in your middleware's handle method

```
    if(Session::has('imperson_by')){
            return $next($request);
    }
    throw new Exception('abc');
```

This is a example you follow in your middleware's handle method